# Как открыть временный файл программой по умолчанию на python?

Tags: python

К примеру во временный файл поместил QR-code, как его показать (открыть в программе по умолчанию)? 
os.startfile() - выдает ошибку: "ValueError: startfile: embedded null character in filepath" 
В связи с данными ответами - уточню, вопрос как открыть именно временный файл!
А не как сохранить файл и открыть его ...

```
import qrcode
import io
import os

data = 'Hello World!'
img = qrcode.make(data)
io_data = io.BytesIO()
img.save(io_data, 'png')
tmp_file = io_data.getvalue()
print(tmp_file)

# Открыть временный файл в программе по умолчанию
os.startfile(tmp_file)
```

Comment: что вообще тут понимается под временным файлом? Файл он или есть, или его нет. "Временный" это абстрактная вещь. Если файл есть на диске, то он открывается так же, как и любой другой файл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте библиотеку [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html):

```py
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

with NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as f:
   ...
```

И дальше работайте с полученным временным файлом - пишите туда ваш код, показывайте его, и не забудьте потом удалить этот файл. Примерно так, если я правильно всё понимаю:

```py
import qrcode
import io
import os
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

data = 'Hello World!'
img = qrcode.make(data)
with NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.png', delete=False) as tmp_file:
    img.save(tmp_file, 'png')
    print(tmp_file.name)
    tmp_file_name = tmp_file.name

# Открыть временный файл в программе по умолчанию
os.startfile(tmp_file_name)

# Удалить временный файл
os.unlink(tmp_file_name)
```

Comment: Спасибо! 
Это то что нужно 

Comment: Можно ли к временному файлу расширение png добавить?

Comment: Да наверное можно прямо прибавить строку ".png" к имени файла

Comment:  
Вопрос только как ?! <br>
По умолчанию файл сохраняется без расширения <br>
Если: os.startfile(tmp_file_name)+‘.png’) <br>
Файл не найден <br>
Если: os.rename(tmp_file, tmp_file+’.png) <br>
Нет доступа к файлу <br>


Comment: @Kjeck Я посмотрел, там есть специальный параметр `suffix=`, я обновил ответ

Comment: В очередной раз спасибо за помощь 
Но странно, при такой конструкции при запуске нет ошибок,  print(tmp_file.name) - печатает имя с расширением,   НО(!)   если без суффикса на os.startfile под виндами открывалось окно с выбором программы для открытия файла, то с суффиксом  ничего не происходит, ни файл не открывается, ни окно с выбором проги для открытия не появляется, как будто строки  os.startfile(tmp_file_name) нет ..., и ошибку тоже не выдает ...